# Save Button on a Table in Javascript Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-table

I have this `javascript` which will allow a user to hit the edit button on a table and edit the content. They can then press save to save the new input. I want to do 4 things which I don't know how to do.

1. I want to remove the border from the `input` box after the edit button has been pressed and then the save button is pressed.
2. Once the save button is pressed I want the `Edit`, `Save`, and `Delete` Button to go back to the same format they were at before pressing Edit.
3. I want the select picker to be `read only` when the `edit` button has not been clicked.
4. Instead of Having the words "`Edit`","`Save`" and "`Delete`" I want to use font awesome icons.

I have uploaded the `JS`, `CSS`, and `HTML` code here.

```js
function edit_row(no) {
  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "block";

  var chore = document.getElementById("chore_row" + no);
  var duration = document.getElementById("duration_row" + no);

  var chore_data = chore.innerHTML;
  var duration_data = duration.innerHTML;

  chore.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='chore_text" + no + "' value='" + chore_data + "'>";
  duration.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='duration_text" + no + "' value='" + duration_data + "'>";
}

function save_row(no) {
  var chore_val = document.getElementById("chore_text" + no).value;
  var duration_val = document.getElementById("duration_text" + no).value;
  var rotation_val = document.getElementById("rotation_text" + no).value;

  document.getElementById("chore_row" + no).innerHTML = chore_val;
  document.getElementById("duration_row" + no).innerHTML = duration_val;
  document.getElementById("rotation_row" + no).innerHTML = rotation_val;

  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";

}

function delete_row(no) {
  document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
}

function add_row() {
  var new_chore = document.getElementById("new_chore").value;
  var new_duration = document.getElementById("new_duration").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("ChoreTbl");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "" +
    "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'>" +
    "   <td id='chore_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_chore + "</td>" +
    "   <td id='duration_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_duration + "</td>" +
    "   <td id='rotation_row'" + table_len + "'>" +
    "<select class='selectpicker1'>" +
    "<option>Daily</option>" +
    "<option>Weekly</option>" +
    "<option>Monthly</option>" +
    "</select>" +
    "</td>" +
    "   <td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit pageButton' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'> " +
    "       <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len + "' value='Save' class='save pageButton' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'> " +
    "       <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete pageButton' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'>" +
    "   </td>" +
    "</tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_chore").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_duration").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_rotation").value = "";
}
```

```css
input {
  background-color: #fff1d9;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #fea680;
}

.pageButton {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="Chores">
  <table id="ChoreTbl" class="choreHead">
    <h1><b>Chore Setting</b></h1>

    <thead>
      <tr class="header" style="color:#008f95;">
        <td id="name_row2"><b>Chore</b></td>
        <td id="country_row2"><b>Time Frame to Complete</b></td>
        <td id="age_row2"><b>Rotation Cycle</b></td>
        <td></td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="row1">
        <td id="chore_row1">Wash Floor</td>
        <td id="duration_row1">3 days</td>
        <td id="rotation_row1">
          <select class="selectpicker1">
            <option>Daily</option>
            <option>Weekly</option>
            <option>Monthly</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit pageButton" onclick="edit_row('1')">
          <input type="button" id="save_button1" value="Save" class="save pageButton" onclick="save_row('1')">
          <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete pageButton" onclick="delete_row('1')">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="new_chore"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="new_duration"></td>
        <td>
          <select class="selectpicker1">
            <option>Daily</option>
            <option>Weekly</option>
            <option>Monthly</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="button" class="add pageButton" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Chore"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You use `document.getElementById("chore_text" + no).value;`, but you have only `#chore_text` element, so `getElementById("chore_text" + no)` returns null

Comment: There's one syntax error here in your concatenation: `<td id='rotation_row'" + table_len + "'>"` (note the extra `'` after "_row"). Also your generated HTML will have some duplicate IDs if you try to add multiple rows without saving. Also, you reference `rotation_text<n>` as an element ID but it never exists. Your `<select>` element never gets an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go you can use the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").attr('disabled', true);
});


function edit_row(no) {
  $("select").attr("disabled", false);
  $("edit_button" + no).show();
  $("save_button" + no).show();

  //document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";
  //document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block";

  var chore = document.getElementById("chore_row" + no);
  var duration = document.getElementById("duration_row" + no);

  var chore_data = chore.innerHTML;
  var duration_data = duration.innerHTML;

  chore.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='chore_text" + no + "' value='" + chore_data + "'>";
  duration.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='duration_text" + no + "' value='" + duration_data + "'>";
}

function save_row(no) {
  $("input[type='text']").css({
    border: 0
  });

  $("#edit_button" + no).show();


  var chore_val = $("chore_text" + no).value;

  var duration_val = $("#duration_text" + no).val();
  var rotation_val = $("#rotation_text" + no).val();

  $("#chore_row" + no).html(chore_val);
  $("#duration_row" + no).html(duration_val);
  $("#rotation_row" + no).html(rotation_val);

  $("#edit_button" + no).show();
  $("#save_button" + no).show();


}

function delete_row(no) {
  document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
}

function add_row() {
  var new_chore = document.getElementById("new_chore").value;
  var new_duration = document.getElementById("new_duration").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("ChoreTbl");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "" +
    "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'>" +
    "   <td id='chore_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_chore + "</td>" +
    "   <td id='duration_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_duration + "</td>" +
    "   <td id='rotation_row'" + table_len + "'>" +
    "<select class='selectpicker1'>" +
    "<option>Daily</option>" +
    "<option>Weekly</option>" +
    "<option>Monthly</option>" +
    "</select>" +
    "</td>" +
    "   <td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit pageButton' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'> " +
    "       <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len + "' value='Save' class='save pageButton' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'> " +
    "       <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete pageButton' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'>" +
    "   </td>" +
    "</tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_chore").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_duration").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_rotation").value = "";
}
```

There are several errors in your code, so i revised it but the `chore_text` name input is not defined and i cant figure out why are you using it so i commented out the lines involved with that input, but the things you addressed are here you can see, just one thing I could not get your `2nd` point **the buttons that you want to switch back to the previous layout**. They never change or maybe I am not getting what you said, I have commented out the portions for you to fix that are buggy, but the problem you are concerned I have added the solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").attr('disabled', true);
});

function edit_row(no) {
  $("#selectpicker" + no).attr("disabled", false);

  $("#save_button" + no).show();

  var chore = $("#chore_row" + no);
  var duration = $("#duration_row" + no);

  var chore_data = chore.html();
  var duration_data = duration.html();

  chore.html("<input type='text' id='chore_text" + no + "' value='" + chore_data + "'>");
  duration.html("<input type='text' id='duration_text" + no + "' value='" + duration_data + "'>");
  $("input[type='text']").css({
    border: 0
  });
}

function save_row(no) {
  var chore_val = $("#chore_text" + no).val();
  var duration_val = $("#duration_text" + no).val();
  var rotation_val = $("#rotation_text" + no).val();

  $("#chore_row" + no).html(chore_val);
  $("#duration_row" + no).html(duration_val);
  $("#rotation_row" + no).html(rotation_val);

  $("#edit_button" + no).show();
  //$("#save_button" + no).hide();
  $("#selectpicker" + no).attr("disabled", true);
}

function delete_row(no) {
  //  $("#row" + no + "").clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html('');
  document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";

}

function add_row() {
  var new_chore = $("#new_chore").val();
  var new_duration = $("#new_duration").val();

  var table = document.getElementById("ChoreTbl");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "" +
    "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'>" +
    "   <td id='chore_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_chore + "</td>" +
    "   <td id='duration_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_duration + "</td>" +
    "   <td id='rotation_row" + table_len + "'>" +
    "<select disabled class='selectpicker1' id='selectpicker" + table_len + "'>" +
    "<option>Daily</option>" +
    "<option>Weekly</option>" +
    "<option>Monthly</option>" +
    "</select>" +
    "</td>" +
    "   <td><i id='edit_button" + table_len + "'  class='fa fa-pencil' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'></i> " +
    "       <i id='save_button" + table_len + "' class='fa fa-floppy-o' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'></i> " +
    "       <i class='fa fa-trash' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></i>" +
    "   </td>" +
    "</tr>";

  $("#new_chore").val();
  $("#new_duration").val();
  //document.getElementById("new_rotation").value = "";
}
```

```css
input {
  background-color: #fff1d9;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #fea680;
}

.pageButton {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="Chores">
  <table id="ChoreTbl" class="choreHead">
    <h1><b>Chore Setting</b></h1>

    <thead>
      <tr class="header" style="color:#008f95;">
        <td id="name_row2"><b>Chore</b></td>
        <td id="country_row2"><b>Time Frame to Complete</b></td>
        <td id="age_row2"><b>Rotation Cycle</b></td>
        <td></td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="row1">
        <td id="chore_row1">Wash Floor</td>
        <td id="duration_row1">3 days</td>
        <td id="rotation_row1">
          <select class="selectpicker1" id="selectpicker1">
            <option>Daily</option>
            <option>Weekly</option>
            <option>Monthly</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <i id="edit_button1" class="fa fa-pencil" onclick="edit_row('1')"></i>
          <i id="save_button1" class="fa fa-floppy-o" onclick="save_row('1')"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-trash" onclick="delete_row('1')"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="new_chore"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="new_duration"></td>
        <td>
          <select class="selectpicker1">
            <option>Daily</option>
            <option>Weekly</option>
            <option>Monthly</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="button" class="add pageButton" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Chore"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: On my original code, try pressing the edit button, changing something and then pressing save. You can see that the format of the buttons changes to one on top of the other with two buttons instead of all three buttons showing up.

Comment: your code throws an error when I click save button, and it has been changed since I last replicated to add the answer, please update the save section and then I will add the revised code with the fixes you want.

Comment: With the newest code, you can't delete or edit a row. On clicking the edit button everything in the row should be editabe. You should be able to delete any row without pressing the edit button. After pressing save, the icons should go back to looking exactly how they looked before even editing.

Comment: that i have understood but regarding your previous comment you said that clicking edit and then saving works and it changes button format,are you talking about when they shift to column view under each other? and they should remain in the same line as they were? plus your edit button disappears as soon it is clicked .

Comment: Yes exactly! I don't want it to disappear. I want them to stay side by side

Comment: i just updated the code snippet , check now if it works as you want it to. @SushmithaKudari

Comment: I have updated my JavaScript to do what I am talking about but now after pressing edit and then save, the very first column in each row is editable and the Dropdown is editable after adding a new row

Comment: your code still breaks at the point when i click save , i just updated the code , run the snippet in my answer and tell if it works as you desire